# contains method ignores equals override

Tags: java, set, overriding, equals

Having `Node` abstract class which `Cell` extends him .

In `Cell` I implemented `public boolean equals(Node cmpCell)` . I `created Set<Node> closeList = new HashSet<Node>();` and when I execute `closeList.contains((Cell) node)` I debugged it and detect that it utterly ignores `Cell equals` I implemented . What I did wrong ?

**Edit :**

I changed in `Cell` to

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object cmpCell)
```

and still `closeList.contains((Cell) node)` doesn't using the above override  .

**2nd Edit :**

In `Cell` class there is 2 members  -

```
int colIndex ;
int rowIndex ;
```

the `equals` override just compare them to that both members of the 2nd class  , I think it would be better I use `HashMap<K, V>` but still I would be glade to know how the `hashCode` should be looks like in such case  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Node cmpCell)
```

This is not a valid override. The syntax of `equals` method of `Object` class is: -

```
public boolean equals(Object)
```

And yes, as pointed out by @JonSkeet in comment,  whenever you are overriding `equals` method, also remember to override `hashCode` method to follow the contract of `equals` and `hashCode`. Because if you don't do that, then even if your `equals` method shows evaluates your instances as equal, the default `hashCode` implementation in `Object` class will generate `different hashCodes` for them, and hence they won't be equal.

Also, ensure that, while calculating `hashcode`, you consider only those attributes, that you used to compare your instances in `equals` method. Else, again you will get incorrect result.

In addition to that, if you are using any IDE like *Eclipse*, it generates a very nicely overridden and compatible `equals` and `hashCode` method for you. You should be better using them.
You need to `right-click` on your class, go to `source` and select `Generate equals and hashCode method`.

Comment: That's why `@Override` should always annotate a method which is supposed to override another. If it doesn't, it leads to a compilation error.

Comment: @URL87.. Please read my edited answer. You also need to override `hashCode` method. Are you using `Eclipse IDE`? If yes, then follow my last paragraph.

Comment: @URL87.. Aren't you using `Eclipse IDE`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't override the [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method.

An object in a hashset is found using the hashcode first. You must always override both or none of the two `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: This certainly could be *part* of the answer. The OP needs to override both hashCode() *and* equals(Object).

Comment: @dystroy could you demonstrate the hashCode accordingthe class as in the edit ?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are three potential issues:

1. You overrode the wrong signature. Should be `public boolean equals(Object)`
2. If you override equals you must implement hashCode
3. Is your equals method symmetric (x.equals(y) implies y.equals(x)) and does it play correctly with polymorphism, ie can you have a Node.equals(Cell) but the reverse be false?

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, `hashCode` and `equals` must be implemented accordingly.

But the question asked here is "*Why isn't the custom equals() called?*". So, the answer is, that Java doesn't support *[multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)*.

### Simple example

If you declare `Object myCell = new Cell()`, then `myCell2.equals(myCell)` can only determine the declared type of myCell, which is `Object`.

### Your case

The signature of the called methods is: `HashSet.contains(Object o)`, with the same consequences as stated above.

You can do something like that, although it isn't a nice solution:

```
public class Cell {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Cell) {
            // your code
        }

        super.equals(o);
    }
}
```